# 2 devices one Apple ID

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, itunes

I am currently testing an app in Test Flight and I have a couple of questions; hopefully someone can help..

1. As mentioned the app is currently in Test Flight. I have noticed that if I have 2 devices registered on the same Apple ID it only allows me to download the app on one of them. Here is the first question: is this problem only related to Test Flight or I will be facing the same issue once the app goes live?
2. My app is a social networking app and in order to start using it the user has to create a profile: insert name, gender and so on.  My second question is: if the problem of the 2 devices and one Apple ID is only related to Test Flight and once the app goes live I will be able to download it on both devices, will I be able to create 2 different profiles or will it automatically pick up the details of the profile on the first device and use it on the second as well?

Thanks

Comment: when you talk about testflight, you mean the testflight website or testflight on itunes connect? when your app is on the app store you can download in any device you have with the same account

Comment: I mean test flight itunes connect. So basically once the app is live I will not be able to create 2 different profiles on 2 devices that are registered on the same Apple ID...

Comment: "it only allows me to download the app on one of them" - Can you elaborate please? I am able to use the TestFlight app and download a beta build on multiple devices. Do you see an error or does it just not install? What happens?

Comment: as far as I know, you can't get the Apple ID from the app, so you can create different profiles from different devices, with the same or different Apple ID

Comment: Hi Gary, When I try to download the app on the second device (after I have installed test flight) it tells me that I have already accepted the invitation for this app.

Comment: Got the same issue... Apple can't possibly be this stupid, right?